# Seminorms and normes

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

How to prove this:

Let $E$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

a seminorm is a norm, if and only if, the unit ball $B(0_E,1)$ does not contain any vector subspace of dimension 1.

Comment: If $n(x) = 0$ for some non zero $x$ then what is $n(tx)$ for any scalar $t$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\norm{\cdot}$ is a norm, every one-dimensional subspace is unbounded: Let $x \ne 0$, then $\norm{\lambda x} = \abs{\lambda}\norm{x} \to \infty, \lambda\to \infty$ as $\norm x \ne 0$.

Now suppose $U$ is a one-dimensional subspace such that $\norm u \le 1$, $u \in U$. Let $x \in U - \{0\}$, than $\lambda x \in U$ for all $\lambda \ge 0$ and hence
$$ \norm x = \frac 1{\lambda} \norm{\lambda x} \le \frac 1\lambda \to 0, \qquad \lambda \to \infty $$
So, $x$ is a non-zero vector with $\norm x = 0$. Therefore, $\norm\cdot$ isn't a norm.

Comment: I understood the first part which proves the direct implication, but the second part, you showed that if U is a one-dimensional subspace contained in the unit ball, then the norm used is not an actual norm, which means you just proved the direct implication again.